# Trying to understand the ordering of setTimeout Promise awaits

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I am trying to understand the order of events in the code.  I hypothesized that after a click event, when Promise 2 (//2) is awaited, the for loop would proceed, after Promise 1 is awaited, and break because `stop` had been set to true prior to Promise 2 being awaited.  However, it isn't predictable.  What is the correct way to think about how these events are ordered in the event loop?

```js
let zeros = new Array(10000).fill(0);

(async () => {

    let stop = false;
    document.addEventListener('click', async ()=>{
        console.log('click');
        stop = true;
        await new Promise((r)=>setTimeout(r)); //2
        stop = false;
    });

    for (let zero of zeros) {
        await new Promise((r)=>setTimeout(r)); //1
        if (stop) {
            break;
        }
        console.log(zero);
    }
})();
```

```html
click here
```

Comment: Are you deliberately not specifying a timeout parameter in milliseconds. If I saw this code this would be a major red flag to me. Are the 'zeros' array a way to _not_ write a `while()` loop? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Evert I'm specifically interested in understanding the rules that determine the order of execution (the order in which events should take place).  Not providing a timeout argument is deliberate.  For example, a possible explanation might be that perhaps if such a timeout is not specified then we should not expect the result to be determinate - I don't know if that is a reasonable expectation or not.

Comment: What is not deterministic?

Comment: @Roberto Zvjerković I've observed the break happen seemingly randomly after a click event given similar circumstances.

Comment: To clarify, not specifying a timeout simply pushes the callback to the bottom of the event queue. It is called a zero delay: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#zero_delays. Not deterministic means the loop will sometimes break and sometimes won't, it appears to be due to the timing of the click, I can't make sense of it myself.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is due to the 4ms minimum pointed out by Andrew: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified

> As specified in the HTML standard, browsers will enforce a minimum timeout of 4 milliseconds once a nested call to setTimeout has been scheduled 5 times.

`await` bundles the code below into a callback function. In the context of a for loop, the remaining iterations are included in that callback, satisfying the condition of a "nested" setTimeout.

You can see this effect if you change `console.log(zero);` to `console.log(new Date().getMilliseconds());` you'll see the first 5 logs are extremely close together, while the next are way further apart.

Here's the breakdown of what's going on:

First we set up our semi-infinite loop:

```js
await new Promise((r1)=>setTimeout(r1)); //1
if (stop) {
   break;
}
```

`(r)=>setTimeout(r)` gets immediately executed, and so `r1()` gets pushed to the bottom of the event queue. After 5 iterations, this gets a timestamp attached that is 4ms in the future. `await` bundles the code underneath into a callback that will also get pushed to the bottom of the event queue when the promise resolves.

On a click:

```js
stop = true;
await new Promise((r2)=>setTimeout(r2)); //2
stop = false
```

`stop = true` and `(r2)=>setTimeout(r2)` get immediately executed, and so `r2()` gets pushed to the bottom of the event queue. Again, `await` bundles the code underneath into a callback that will also get pushed to the bottom of the event queue when the promise resolves.

So there are six events that are happening:

1. `r1` is pushed to the bottom of the event queue with a 4ms timeout
2. `r1` reaches the top of the event queue. If 4ms has elapsed, `r1` is executed and `if (stop) break;` is pushed to the bottom of the event loop. If 4ms has not elapsed, `r1` gets pushed to the bottom again.
3. `if (stop) break;` reaches the top of the event queue and is executed, if the loop is not broken, event 1 is executed again.
4. user clicks, `stop = true` is executed and `r2` is pushed to the bottom of the event queue.
5. `r2` reaches the top of the event queue and is executed, `stop = false` is pushed to the bottom of the event queue.
6. `stop = false` reaches the top of the event queue and is executed.

You can see that for the loop to break, event 3 needs to happen after event 4 and before event 6. With zero delays, there is no possible event order where event 3 does NOT happen between 4 and 6 on a click. This is due to the fact that nothing pushed to the bottom of the queue will ever be re-pushed to the bottom of the queue. But with one being a zero delay and one being a 4ms delay, here is one such order that would not break the loop:

- event 1 (`r1` pushed with 4ms timeout)
- event 2 (4ms has elapsed, `if (stop) break;` pushed)
- event 3 & 1 (`if (stop) break;` executed, loop not broken, `r1` pushed w/ 4ms timeout)
- event 4 (user click, `stop = true`, `r2` pushed)
- event 2 (4ms has not elapsed, `r1` pushed again)
- event 5 (`stop = false` pushed)
- event 2 (4ms has elapsed, `if (stop) break;` pushed)
- event 6 (`stop = false` executed)
- event 3 & 1 (`if (stop) break;` executed, loop not broken, `r1` pushed w/ 4ms timeout)

So congratulations, you made a race condition in a single-threaded language.

---

Synchronizing the two timeouts with something greater than 4ms *seems* to solve the issue

```js
let zeros = new Array(10000).fill(0);

(async () => {
    let stop = false;
    document.addEventListener('click', async ()=>{
        console.log('click');
        stop = true;
        await new Promise((r)=>setTimeout(r,5)); //2
        stop = false;
    });

    for (let zero of zeros) {
        await new Promise((r)=>setTimeout(r,5)); //1
        if (stop) {
            break;
        }
        console.log(zero);
    }
})();
```

---

However it is still theoretically possible for the loop to not be broken. The following event order would allow the loop to continue:

- event 1 (`r1` pushed w/ 5ms timeout)
- event 4 (user click, `stop = true`, `r2` pushed w/ 5ms timeout)
- event 2 (5ms has not elapsed from event 1, `r1` pushed again)

It is possible that events 1 and 4 happened quickly, but events 2 and 5 took some time between - this is what allows event 5 to complete before event 2.

- event 5 (5ms has elapsed from event 4, `stop = false` pushed)
- event 2 (5ms has elapsed from event 1, `if (stop) break;` pushed)
- event 6 (`stop = false` executed)
- event 3 & 1 (`if (stop) break;` executed, loop not broken, `r1` pushed)

I haven't yet been able to reproduce it, but hey let's just not code like this.

---

To achieve what you're trying to do is very simple, just use `setInterval` instead of a loop. This will cycle the callback to the back of the queue after execution, which allows other events to be executed between. That's opposed to `while` and `for` loops which will block any other execution while running.

```js
let stop = false;

document.addEventListener('click', () => (stop = true));

const id = setInterval(() => {
  console.log('running');
  if (stop) {
    console.log('stopped');
    clearInterval(id);
  }
});
```

Comment: I think this is a great point - my proposition was essentially that when both timeouts have a delay of zero/undefined, in practice the browser will prioritize setTimeout//2 because it is in response to a UI event. You've demonstrated how this prioritization does not happen if the requested delays are at least around 5ms or higher. I think that our answers are therefore entirely compatible.

Comment: It will execute the `click` listener before pulling from the event queue, as event callbacks are not pushed to the queue, but the setTimeout within the listener will have no such prioritization, nor will the `await` callback. You can see that happening in event 4. They simply get pushed to the back of the queue.

Comment: "event callbacks are not pushed to the queue" - are you suggesting that when a user clicks, a macrotask for that click event handler is not created and added to the queue? I think it is a macrotask. The macrotask diagram here says so: https://javascript.info/event-loop I think that the macrotask order is always obeyed, and the only thing that has prioritization is the exact duration of tiny setTimeouts, where it will be unpredictable when the timeout expires and a macrotask is created in the queue for the setTimeout callback

Comment: I believe UI events are executed immediately after the current task, but I could be wrong. If they are pushed to the back of the queue it doesn't make a huge difference. setTimeout callbacks exist in the queue from the moment you call setTimeout, the browser will just check the timestamp, if it hasn't expired then it will push it to the back again. Yeah the order can be unpredictable if they are not zero delays, because they have the chance of being re-pushed, changing the order. Zero delays will never be re-pushed though, hence their order is entirely predictable.

Comment: @AndrewParks did a quick test, UI events are pushed to the back of the queue just like setTimeout callbacks. So I was wrong about that, there is no prioritization given to them.

Comment: Here's the test in case you're curious: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fhmrhq?file=index.ts,index.html

Comment: @ChrisHamilton Do you have any guidance on how to break from a while loop when the mouse is clicked given that this isn't the right way to do it?

Comment: @stackhatter Use `setInterval` not a loop. I put an example at the end of my answer. If you need to iterate an array or something, just increment an integer on every interval.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is single-threaded. There is a queue of macrotasks (setTimeout callbacks and click handlers) and another of microtasks (for resuming code that was waiting for async functions/promises). Microtasks always have priority over macrotasks.

The only way the macrotask for executing the click handler can run is after line `//1` suspends due to the use of setTimeout.

But then, the click handler sets `stop=true` and calls setTimeout itself, causing itself to then suspend too.

Now, there is a race. Which setTimeout will return first: the one on line `//1` or the one on line `//2`?

If the delay on both setTimeouts is the same (or when both have an unspecified delay parameter), you would expect them to run in the order that the setTimeouts were initiated. However, you cannot rely on your browser to be predictable when it comes to setTimeout.

If you specify a delay of a 100 ms in your setTimeout call on line `//2`, the loop will more reliably break after a click. However, even this is not absolutely guaranteed!

Your browser will decide for itself how long to delay, and does not make any guarantees.

You'll notice that when no delays are specified, in Chrome, if you click slowly, the loop will rarely break. However, if you click rapidly, there is a high chance of it breaking. The difference is not the number of clicks, it's whether you click quickly. (Note: sometimes when I repeat the experiment, it does break far more often. The browser is very unpredictable!)

Reasons for unpredictable setTimeout delays are listed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified). In particular,

> The timeout can also fire later than expected if the page (or the
> OS/browser) is busy with other tasks

This is why clicking rapidly causes the setTimeouts to delay differently than when you click slowly. I would guess that since the setTimeout in `//2` is in response to a UI event, the browser would decide to prioritize that setTimeout in order to try to make the web page more responsive. Thus, the loop would not break. However, when you click quickly, the browser would then start deferring all setTimeouts with random extra delays, causing them to suddenly execute in a different order.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about the 4ms minimum on nested timeouts, I wonder if that's what's kicking in here on the for loop.

Comment: The entire event queue could be emptied within 4ms, causing `//2` with a 4ms delay to be re-pushed to the bottom rather than executed, since it's timeout has not elapsed.

Comment: You can see my answer below.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton btw I've deleted my earlier comments here, and I've upvoted your answer because I think you're right about the nested 4ms issue